# DateValue format issue between worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, date, format

I'm having issues bringing a date from one worksheet to another. When using the below formula if the date can conform to both American and Australian format it decides to convert it to American (mm/dd/yyyy when i need it as dd/mm/yyyy).

Both the source cell and target cell are both formatted alike and the cell format itself doesn't get changed via the vba, it just jumbles up what is a day and what is a month.

```
Sub BOCMS()

Dim date1 As String
Dim date2 As String
date1 = Format(DateValue(Sheet1.Range("L13").Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")
date2 = Format(DateValue(Sheet1.Range("L14").Value), "dd/mm/yyyy")

Workbooks.Open (ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Manual date res acts\BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm")
Workbooks("BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm").Activate

Workbooks("BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Res Activity Report").Range("O1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.Value = Format(date1, "dd/mm/yyyy")
Workbooks("BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm").Worksheets("Res Activity Report").Range("Q1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.Value = Format(date2, "dd/mm/yyyy")


ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
Application.Run "'BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm'!RunReport"
End Sub
```

Any tips would be fantastic

Comment: Good reason not to use strings that only _look_ like dates.  Deal with the underlying date Serial numbers instead.

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand what you're saying. I've tried it as Date instead of String and get the same result. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have two installs with different locals to test on, so this is untested, but should be close

```
Sub BOCMS()
    Dim date1 As Double
    Dim date2 As Double
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    date1 = Sheet1.Range("L13").Value
    date2 = Sheet1.Range("L14").Value

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Manual date res acts\BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm")

    With wb2.Worksheets("Res Activity Report").Range("O1")
        .ClearContents
        .Value = date1
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With

    With wb2.Worksheets("Res Activity Report").Range("Q1")
        .ClearContents
        .Value = date2
        .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    End With


    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Run "'BOC - Res Activity Report.xlsm'!RunReport"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is perfect. Have never used Double so will have to look into i t for future purposes. Thank you again.

Comment: For research purposes, look into `DateTime Serial Number`.  [A place to start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264202.aspx)